# CMD - is not recognized as an internal/external command

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt

I have a problem with "**Command Prompt**" :

[image]

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: what do you want to do with program files??

Comment: `cd Program Files`

Comment: I want to access C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\BIN>stsadm -o uninstallfeature -name UserInterfaceWayBillActions -force

Comment: first navigate to that directory through command :   cd s C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\BIN and then execute your command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    You have to follow two steps for this :

    1.navigate to that directory through command :
 cd C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\BIN

    2. Then execute your command. 

     stsadm -o uninstallfeature -name UserInterfaceWayBillActions -force
```

Answer (score 1):

type in

`C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\BIN\stsadm -o uninstallfeature -name UserInterfaceWayBillActions -force`

and hit enter